# How to disable response data compression in Express?

Tags: javascript, express, server

I want to receive in response from the server 'Content-Length'
For this i want to disable gzip compression. I use for this comprassion middleware:

```js
const shouldCompress = (req, res) => {
    if(req.headers['x-no-comprassion']) {
        return false
    } 
}

app.use(compression({threshold: 5, filter: shouldCompress}))
```

And also send 'x-no-comprassion' header from client, but it still doesn't work.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`content-length` is sent automatically by express api when the response is sent:
https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/28db2c2c5cf992c897d1fbbc6b119ee02fe32ab1/lib/response.js#L194.

Compression activitated or not, this header should be present.

Comment: But he is not in the response

Comment: Length comes only when the response does not contain a header 'Content-encoding'. When the response is not encoded, the length appears in the response

Answer (score 0):

I've tested with this code:

```js
const compression = require('compression');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

function shouldCompress(req, res) {
  if (req.headers['x-no-compression']) return false;
  return compression.filter(req, res);
}

app.use(compression({threshold: 5, filter: shouldCompress}));
app.get('/', function (req, res) { res.json({state: "ok"}); });
app.listen(8888, () => { console.log(`Started http://localhost:8888`) });
```

When I launch
`curl localhost:8888 -v`
=> I have: `Content-Length: 14`

When I launch
`curl localhost:8888 -v -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate'`
=> No content-length in response, and a binary output
`Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal.`

When I launch
`curl localhost:8888 -v -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'x-no-compression: 1'`
=> I have: `Content-Length: 14`

So, there is no issue, it works as excepted.
How did you send the header? Did you set a value?